# How to avoid extra HTTP request on test beginning?

Tags: php, testing, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

Let's say I have a test like this:

```
class SortTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setHost('192.168.1.1');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://some.url/');
        $this->setBrowser('chrome');
    }

    public function testFoo()
    {
        $this->url('/foo');
    }

    public function testBar()
    {
        $this->url('/bar');
    }
}
```

If I run this test I will see that each time the root page is loaded, and after that the required `/foo` or `/bar` is opened.

If I comment out or move `setBrowserUrl()` call to the test method - I get `Undefined index: browserUrl`

So is there a way to avoid that redundant HTTP request on test method set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is there a way to avoid that redundant HTTP request on test method set up

By setting browser url to empty string `$this->setBrowserUrl('');` but then it requires every other url to be absolute `$this->url('http://some.url/foo');` This will not prevent selenium from trying to access empty url, but will make it a lot quicker, especially if start page is heavy

Comment: Yep. Seems like no compromise